# Functions: Quasi-convex and quasi-concave

Tags: functions

Can a non-increasing function be both quasi-concave and quasi-convex? I know that non-decreasing function is both but does this hold for non-increasing as well?

Comment: Yes. Pick a non-increasing function and multiply it by "-1". Then it will be non-decreasing, so it is quasi-convex and quasi-concave. Then to conclude that $f$ is both, just use the equivalence: $f$ is quasi-concave$ \Leftrightarrow $ $-f$ is quasi-convex.

Comment: The definition of quasi-convexity, that is: $f$ is quasi-convex if for any $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, the set $f^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ is convex can be defined equivalently with the interval $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$

Comment: Did you try to look for example among *linear* functions?

Comment: Thank you. I will try this

Comment: Suppose f is a strictly quasi-concave function. If f is also a concave function, is it necessarily strictly concave? @AndréPorto

Comment: No. $f(x)=x$ is strictly quasi-concave and concave, but not strictly concave.